# Can composite field consists of two fermions cause cosmic inflation rather one scalar field?

Tags: fermions, cosmological-inflation

Inflation is triggered by one scalar field, can a field composite of fermions do the same in the early universe

Comment: You mean like Cooper pairs ?  There has been some [discussion](http://arxiv.org/pdf/physics/0610247) along these lines, but hopefully someone who actually knows something about this will respond.

Comment: A slightly more relevant [reference](http://arxiv.org/pdf/gr-qc/0305054).

Comment: Yes,I mean like Cooper pairs, thanks also for the links.